# Filtering a dgv using its Datasource(dt).DefaultView.RowFilter with a concatenated string

Tags: vb.net, datatable, datagridview, rowfilter, defaultview

For some reason when I apply my dgvBarcodes.Datasource.Defaultview.Rowfilter = strDGVBarcodesFilter it's looking for (column "Test"), instead of filtering the rows on column "LongDescription=Test". This is unexpected behaviour. How do I get the .DefaultView.RowFilter to filter all rows based on "LongDescription=Test"?

the strDGVBarcodesFilter in this example = "LongDescription=Test", when moused over, and the error I'm getting is "System.Data.EvaluateException: 'Cannot find column [test].'"

Event handler:

> ```
>   If txtLongDescription2.Text IsNot Nothing Then
>         Dim strLongDescription As String = txtLongDescription2.Text 
>         Dim strLongDescriptionFilter As String = ""
>         If strLongDescription = "" Then
>             strLongDescriptionFilter = ""
>         Else
>             strLongDescriptionFilter = "LongDescription=" & strLongDescription
>         End If
>         Dim strDGVBarcodesFilter As String = fnBuildFilterString(strMainBrandFilter, strSubBrandFilter, strLongDescriptionFilter)
>         dgvBarcodes.DataSource.DefaultView.Rowfilter = strDGVBarcodesFilter
>     End If
> ```

Filter string builder function;

```
Private Function fnBuildFilterString(strFilterComponent1 As String, strFilterComponent2 As String, Optional strFilterComponent3 As String = "", Optional strFilterComponent4 As String = "", Optional strFilterComponent5 As String = "") As String
    'Essentially it builds this; strMainFilter = strFilterComponent1 & " AND " & strFilterComponent2 & " AND " & strFilterComponent3 & " AND " & strFilterComponent4 & " AND " & strFilterComponent5
    Dim strMainFilter As String = "" 'Reset the masterfilter string to be empty

    If strFilterComponent1 <> "" Then  'If the filter component isn't empty
        If strMainFilter = "" Then 'And if the masterfilter is empty
            strMainFilter = strFilterComponent1 'Adds the filter component to the masterfilter string
        Else 'The masterfilter isn't empty
            strMainFilter &= " AND " & strFilterComponent1 'then it adds " AND " &field to the masterfilter string
        End If
    Else 'Filter component is empty, do nothing
    End If 'check next component

    If strFilterComponent2 <> "" Then  'If the filter component isn't empty
        If strMainFilter <> "" Then 'And if the masterfilter isn't empty
            strMainFilter &= " AND " & strFilterComponent2 'then it adds " AND " &field to the masterfilter string
        Else 'The masterfilter is empty
            strMainFilter = strFilterComponent2 'Adds the filter component to the masterfilter string
        End If
    Else 'Filter component is empty, do nothing
    End If 'check next component        

    If strFilterComponent3 <> "" Then  'If the filter component isn't empty
        If strMainFilter <> "" Then 'And if the masterfilter isn't empty
            strMainFilter &= " AND " & strFilterComponent3 'then it adds " AND " &field to the masterfilter string
        Else 'The masterfilter is empty
            strMainFilter = strFilterComponent3 'Adds the filter component to the masterfilter string
        End If
    Else 'Filter component is empty, do nothing
    End If 'check next component

    If strFilterComponent4 <> "" Then  'If the filter component isn't empty
        If strMainFilter <> "" Then 'And if the masterfilter isn't empty
            strMainFilter &= " AND " & strFilterComponent4 'then it adds " AND " &field to the masterfilter string
        Else 'The masterfilter is empty
            strMainFilter = strFilterComponent4 'Adds the filter component to the masterfilter string
        End If
    Else 'Filter component is empty, do nothing
    End If 'check next component

    If strFilterComponent5 <> "" Then  'If the filter component isn't empty
        If strMainFilter <> "" Then 'And if the masterfilter isn't empty
            strMainFilter &= " AND " & strFilterComponent5 'then it adds " AND " &field to the masterfilter string
        Else 'The masterfilter is empty
            strMainFilter = strFilterComponent5 'Adds the filter component to the masterfilter string
        End If
    Else 'Filter component is empty, do nothing
    End If 'check next component

    Return strMainFilter
End Function
```

Comment: Don't bind and filter like that. Add a `BindingSource` to your form, bind the `DataTable` to the `BindingSource` and the `BindingSource` to the grid, then set the `Filter` property of the `BindingSource`. It ends up doing the same thing but is less messy.

Comment: don't bind like what exactly? I haven't shown how I bound my dgv  to the dt?
Can you elaborate why adding a BindingSource is a superior method over binding the dgv to the dt directly, and just changing the defaultview property of the dt? That's what I've been advised before and I do not understand whats the difference or it's pros/cons. IF it works as intended, it should be just as simple/clean? Understanding the distinction would help me along on my coding journey.

Answer (score 0):

Think about what you're doing there. If you did this in your VB code:

```vb
Dim someStringVariable As String

'...

If someStringVariable = Test Then
```

would you expect that to compare that variable to the literal text "Test"? Of course not, because there's no literal text there. You have to wrap text in double-quotes to indicate that it's a literal `String`. If you expect to use literal text in your SQL code (a filter is a SQL `WHERE` clause) then you need to do the equivalent. How do you denote literal text in SQL code? With single-quotes.

Here's the proper way to do what you want to do:

```vb
strLongDescriptionFilter = $"LongDescription = '{strLongDescription}'"
```

and:

```vb
Dim criteria As New List(Of String)

If Not String.IsNullOrWhitespace(strFilterComponent1) Then
    criteria.Add(strFilterComponent1)
End If

'Etc.

Return String.Join(" AND ", criteria)
```

There are other improvements you could make to but that's probably enough for a first step.

Comment: I would expect the dgv to show the filtered rows where (column"LongDescription") = strLongDescription. thats how it works when I put the dt into a dv first, but for some reason when I use the defaultview it is looking for column strLongdescription and I don't understand why it doesn't behave the same way
Also, I have no clue what your code example is supposed to represent
`strLongDescriptionFilter = $"LongDescription = '{strLongDescription}'"`
AFAIK, $ is not used in VB, and you haven't provided a value for the filter string, because it's commented out so now it only says "LongDescription="

Comment: @Polardog, I'm not inclined to fight against such a strong determination to be wrong. The information I have provided will fix your issue and simplify your code significantly. It is your prerogative to not use it.

Comment: @Polardog, for the record, `$"LongDescription = '{strLongDescription}'"` is functionally equivalent to `String.Format("LongDescription = '{0}'", strLongDescription)`, which is functionally equivalent to `"LongDescription = '" & strLongDescription & "'"`, which you would have discovered if you had tried it as suggested instead of telling me that, AFAYK, I'm wrong.

Comment: I found out why the value for the filter string was commented out, I misplaced the ". Also, the reason why it used to work with dv's and not a default view was due to the datatype used and had nothing to do with the dv;  strLongDescriptionFilter = "LongDescription=" & intLongDescription works if intLongDescription is an integer, but not if its a string. I don't know anything about SQL, which is why your initial explanation went right over my head. still don't understand what the $ is used for but apparantly its crucial because without it the whole thing turns into a string.

Comment: .... Rather than a string with a variable in it.
I also now appreciate your second code block, it looks a lot cleaner and shorter than my string builder. Although I don't understand yet why you use a list instead of a stringarray. 
@jmcilhinney Thank you for your contribution. it was helpful

Comment: The use of the $ indicates string interpolation. You can read the documentation for the `String.Format` method to see how it is used to perform composite formatting. String interpolation is basically native language support for that `String.Format` method. That's why i said that they are functionally equivalent in an earlier comment. String interpolation is just "syntactic sugar" and the compiler treats it as a call to `String.Format`.

Comment: The reason I used a `List(Of String)` is that, based on your code, you won't know how many items it will contain. It starts empty and then you add zero to five items to it in `If` blocks. When done, those items are combined into a single `String` with and `AND` operator between each pair, regardless of how many there are. If there's none then you end up with an empty `String`. If there's one then you get just that value with no `AND` operators. If there are two or more then you get an `AND` operator between each pair.